# Incrementing a numpy array in numba

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, numba

I have a problem that essentially amounts to counting, and I need to parallelize my implementation. I am lazy and want to continue coding in Python, so I hope to use numba.

The serial implementation is something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def count_stuff(stuff):
    count=np.zeros(len(stuff))
    for thing in stuff:
        if some_condition(thing):
            i=some_integer_function(thing)
            count[i]+=1
    return count
```

However, I expect the following naive numba implementation is guaranteed to fail due to a race condition:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit,prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def count_stuff_parallel(stuff):
    count=np.zeros(len(stuff))
    for i in prange(len(stuff)):
        thing=stuff[i]
        if some_condition(thing):
            j=some_integer_function(thing)
            count[j]+=1
    return count
```

The problem is the different threads are trying to access the array `count` simultaneously. A typical solution is to give each thread its own private `count` and then add them up at the end. However, I have no idea how to do this in numba. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do that in general. The two common methods are to use either atomic accesses or an array-based reduction. AFAIK, the former is not possible yet in Numba because atomic operations are not yet supported on CPU. The second solution can be done in Numba but this is not so trivial since Numba does not provide any easy way to do it (unlike OpenMP does in C/C++/Fortran for example). You need to do the work manually. The thing is there is another bad news: there is AFAIK no standard way to create thread-private variables anymore in Numba... That being said, you can divide the problem in a fixed number of chunks, compute them in parallel and do the reduction sequentially. This si rather cumbersome but it may worth it. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def count_stuff_parallel(stuff):
    nChunks = 8  # To tune
    count = np.zeros((nChunks, len(stuff)))
    for i1 in prange(nChunks):
        start = len(stuff) * i1 // nChunks
        stop = len(stuff) * (i1 + 1) // nChunks
        for i2 in range(start, stop):
            thing = stuff[i2]
            if some_condition(thing):
                j = some_integer_function(thing)
                count[i1, j] += 1
    return count.sum(axis=0)            # If not supported by Numba: write a loop instead
```

Ideally, `nChunks` should be either big or a multiple of the number of threads. However, `len(stuff) / nChunks` need to be also relatively small for the final reduction to be fast. Note that usingmultiple thread only worth it if `len(stuff)` is huge or if the function `some_integer_function` is slow.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the specifics I think. If you have memory to spare, a more pure Numpy approach, where you evaluate everything at once, probably allows much better parallelization (at the expense of memory).

```py
crit = some_condition(stuff)
idx = some_integer_function(crit)
count = np.bincount(idx)
```

Without a specific example it's impossible to say what would be optimal.

Comment: *"probably allows much better parallelization"* Numpy functions are *not* multi-threaded (only BLAS routine are overall). A simple Numba code can be as fast as `np.bincount` (in fact it can be a bit faster once optimized). Besides, binning cannot be vectorized using SIMD instruction either (for sufficiently large arrays). Thus, `np.bincount` is clearly sequential.

Comment: Of course. My main point was that you can perform each step for all items, before moving on. Compared to doing it per-item as in the Numba example. The first two steps are probably easily written in Numba as well, and for the final summation a batched approach could be used.